# DynamicSlope not working in d3 funnel chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I trying to d3 funnel chart with 0 values its not working properly.I enabled dynamicSlope option is true funnel chart not working.

**See my example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3x265bLj/7/

I added six values l0,l1,l2....L6 and l3 value is 0.Once i enabled dynamicSlope option is true Funnel chart only showing L0,L1,L2 value only but need L3,L4,L5.

```
const data = [
                ['l0', 13],
                ['l1', 7],
                ['l2', 12],
                ['l3', 0],
                ['l4', 8],
                ['l5', 3]
            ];
            const options = {
                chart: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 450,
                    bottomWidth: 1 / 2,
                    bottomPinch: 1,
                    inverted: false,
                    horizontal: false,
                    animate: 0,
                    curve: {
                        enabled: true,
                        height: 20,
                        shade: -0.4
                    }
                },
                block: {
                    dynamicSlope: true,
                    dynamicHeight: true,
                    highlight: true
                }
            };

            const chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
            chart.draw(data, options);
```

**Console Issues:**

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,562.5 LNaN,5…".
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,562.5 LNaN,5…".
```

Means
 The function try to convert data to height format, but you input 0 that means 0 height,  the function reject you.

> what is the purpose of drawing 0 data? axample, if the function can do
>   it, the data will not showing on the chart, because it has 0 height,
>   am i correct?

thare is 2 solution for your problem, first you change the data value to 0.01 before draw it

```
var data = [
                ['l0', 13],
                ['l1', 7],
                ['l2', 12],
                ['l3', 0],
                ['l4', 8],
                ['l5', 3]
            ];
var newdata = data.map(function (d,i){
              var new_d = d
              if (new_d[1] == 0){
                 new_d[1] = 0.01
              }
              return new_d
            })
chart.draw(newdata, options);
```

second, you add the filter function before draw it

```
var data = [
                ['l0', 13],
                ['l1', 7],
                ['l2', 12],
                ['l3', 0],
                ['l4', 8],
                ['l5', 3]
            ];
var newdata = data.filter(function (d,i){
              return d[1] !== 0
            })
chart.draw(newdata, options);
```